# symfony1 enums with column aggregation inheritence

Tags: doctrine, symfony-1.4

I have a profile table that saves all profiles for all user.
I have different types of users and want each type of user to have different select options for choosing a certain field.
So both user types can choose how long they want to register for, but the have different options - one can choose 2 years and the other cant.
The schema.yml looks something like this:

UserProfile:

```
columns:
    username:
        type: string(255)
        notnull: true
        unique: false
```

WriterUserProfile:

```
inheritance:
    type: column_aggregation
    extends: UserProfile
columns:
    register_time:
        type: enum
        values:
            - 6 months
            - 1 year
            - 2 years
            - Other
        default: other
```

ReaderUserProfile:

```
inheritance:
    type: column_aggregation
    extends: UserProfile
columns:
    register_time:
        type: enum
        values:
            - 6 months
            - 1 year
            - Other
        default: other
```

For some reason I am unable to select the '2 year' option - the form gives an 'invalid' error.
Does the '2 years' and 'Other' coincide with eachother because they are both the 3rd option?

Comment: Shouldn't default be 'Other' and not 'other'?

Comment: maybe, but that seems to be working. My problem is that '2 years' is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Are there other fields which are not common? This one field only not enough cause to use column aggregation. Anyway, if the same field appears in multiple sub-classes than the field should be moved up and field names should be unique among all related classes (UserProfile, WriterUserProfile, ReaderUserProfile in your case).

You can change the options of the choice field in a form:

```
$choices = array('0' => 'a', '1' => 'b');
$this->getWidget('register_time')->setOption('choices', $choices);
$this->getValidator('register_time')->setOption('choices', array_keys($choices));
```